# Determine type of sub tables

Tags: mysql, database

**Problem:**
I have modelled my mySQL tables to emulate inheritance between tables, for example:

[image: Example model]

Is there any good way to query for employees and output which type of employee they are?

The desired output would be:

```
id   name                             salary     type
------------------------------------------------------------
1    John Doe                         2000       executive
2    Jane Doe                         1000       manager
3    Nick Carter                      500        intern
```

Any help appreciated!

Comment: While you can use the select provided in the answer, I recommend you change your design and add a column "employee_type" to employee. Your current structure will have problems when either multiple or none of (intern, manager, executive) have rows for one employee.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could have one table for maintaining the type of the employe however in this case you can do as

```
select 
e.* ,
case 
  when i.employee_id is not null then 'intern'
  when m.employee_id is not null then 'manager'
  when ex.employee_id is not null then 'executive'
end as `type` 
from employee e 
left join intern i on i.employee_id = e.id
left join manager m on m.employee_id = e.id
left join executive ex on ex.employee_id = e.id
```